# Q.all not calling promises from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, coffeescript, q

guys. I'm trying to migrate users, but the promises are never called.

```
  User = mongoose.model 'User'
  User.find({"hisId" : {$exists : true}}).exec (err, doc)->
    if err
      console.error err
      process.exit()
    if not doc or doc.length < 1
      process.exit()
    i = 0
    promiseArray = []
    while i < doc.length
      updateFunc = (doc) ->
        defer = Q.defer()
        User.update({
          "_id" : ObjectId(doc[i].juniorId)
          "friends.user": ObjectId(doc[i]._id)
        },{
          $set:
            "friends.$.canAdmin" : true
        }, (err, updateResult) =>
          if err
            console.error err
            defer.reject()
          defer.resolve()
        )
        return defer.promise
      updateFunc.bind(null, doc)
      promiseArray.push updateFunc
      i++
    Q.all(promiseArray).then(->
      console.log 'Why did get here before promises all fulfilled?'
    ).done ( ->
      process.exit()
    )
```

I tried it with the Q.promise solution but it does not work either.  Promise array is filled with function, I checked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promise array is filled with function, but it's not filled with a promise, therefore it's fulfilled.

Instead do `promiseArray.push(updateFunc(doc))`

Comment: Ah, I totally missed that. Thanks.